# Apache server does not connect to Django

Tags: python, django, apache, configuration

So, I'm running Apache2 on a Linux machine, and I'm trying to serve pages with Django 1.3. I found a guide to do this [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yAyWM-iEIos).

I have the `django.wsgi` configured, the `settings.py` configured, and the database created and successfully in sync with Django. However, when I try to visit the website, I am shown a page served by Apache, instead of Django. I get no errors/warnings at all.

I put print statements in both `django.wsgi` and `settings.py` (since they're both just python files), but nothing gets printed.

Does anyone have any idea as to what may be going wrong or any diagnostic steps I might be able to take?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like Apache's misconfigured, in which case this might be better suited to ServerFault.  But regardless, we're going to need a lot more information, starting with the contents of your Apache site configuration.

Comment: I haven't changed any Apache configuration at all. Any tips on how I should?

Comment: Ah, well that would be why it's not working. :-)  You need to tell Apache to actually use WSGI and how to map URLs to scripts/files.  You're going to want to start by reading https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modwsgi/ and take further questions to ServerFault, since this is not a programming issue at this point.

Comment: That sounds like modwsgi is not installed or loaded.

Comment: @ConradShultz Someone I know configured django/apache according to the tutorial above, and didn't need to configure apache at all. 
@Rach I'm pretty sure modwsgi is not installed. I tried making from source, but I don't seem to have `apxs` installed. It seems that I can't separately install this, but that it comes bundled with apache. Is there a way to fix this or do I need to reinstall apache?

Comment: I saw your link is to YouTube and I don't really have time to watch a video, but in general Apache *must* be configured to do anything useful.  Now, in certain limited cases (i.e. where only one site is served, out of the DocumentRoot) I could imagine you getting away without configuration, but that sounds dangerous.  As for mod_wsgi, what platform are you on? You normally don't build modules from source.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu, and as it turns out, `mod_wsgi`is installed. I realized just now that I can use `apt-get` to install it, and its already there. I understand that Apache must be configured, but I just wanted to make sure that the basic functionality of connecting Apache and Django works, before going any further. I guess I'm back to square one, unfortunately...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everyone has said in the comments, you need to add a `WSGIServerAlias` directive to the Apache configuration before anything will work. Otherwise, Apache can't possibly know to use WSGI to serve your site.

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing, but forgot to update here. Thanks to everyone that helped!